# Visual Studio Code not showing suggestions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm following a Blazor tutorial in Visual Studio Code. However I don't get VS Code suggestions such as missing assemblies (when my context file inherits from `DbContext` of Entity Framework Core) or if I have a public interface, I don't get the "Implement interface" option. The bulb does not showing up in any place, so I have to write all the code manually.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall VS Code, deleting the preferences folder first. Also, restarting Omnisharp but nothing do the trick. My sln file is recognized, however.

[image: not showing suggestions]

Environment:

- VS Code 1.54.1 (system setup)
- .NET Core 5.1

Extensions:

- Activitus Bar
- Blazor Snippets
- C# (Omnisharp)
- C# Extensions
- C# XML Documentation Comments
- Razor+
- Path Intellisense
- Nuget Package Manager
- dotnet
- Dotnet Core Essentials (DCE)

Any suggestions? Or is it better to go back to Visual Studio?

Comment: I've found that suggestions only work when the package is already added to the project. Wonder if that's the case.

Comment: @mmking which package? Seems I'm missing someting...

Comment: I would try restarting Omnisharp, and checking omnisharp's output to see if something's wrong with it. I am currently using VS Code as main editor for my C# projects and it works flawlessly.

Comment: Assemblies/nuget packages. Sorry for not being specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reinstall the Nuget package with the NugetGallery extension.
If it has not worked try to type `dotnet restore` in Command Prompt at the project directory.
Checking the dependencies of the project may resolve the problem.